# Get html from iframe

Tags: html, vbscript

I am attempting to strip the HTML from an iframe using vbscript. Any decent way to do this? Here is the only suggestion I found online, and it is pulling the HTML from the main page, not the iframe:

```
pageHTML = ie.document.All("ExternalQuestionIFrame").Document.Body.innerHTML
```

ExternalQuestionIFrame is the name attribute. No ID tagged.

Comment: Does the iframe point to page inside the same domain? If not, what you ask for is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the iFrame's contentWindow.

```
Set myFrame = ie.document.getElementByID("ExternalQuestionIFrame")
Set internalContent = myFrame.contentWindow
pageHTML = internalContent.Document.Body.innerHTML
```

This can probably be cleaned up into a one-liner, but I like to set my objects a little piece at a time.

contentWindow reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp